# How to pass a var list to another winform

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I have this code. How can I pass `smallGroups` to the `UpdatePlayer` form. I need to be able to take the data generated to the var list, and use it in `UpdatePlayer` to populate `combobox`.

```
public class GroupsPlayers
{
    public string GroupID;
    public string GroupName;
}

public void Groups() {
    var smallGroups = new List<GroupsPlayers>();


    while(rd.Read())
    {
        var currentPlayer = new GroupsPlayers() {

        };

        smallGroups.Add(currentPlayer);
    }


    MessageBoxResult userResponse = MessageBox.Show(msgBoxMsg, "Groups Manager", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if(userResponse == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        UpdatePlayer frmPlayers = new UpdatePlayer(this, smallGroups);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have above? Do you not have a property in UpdatePlayer to store smallGroups in? And then set that property as your combobox's datasource during load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If GroupsPlayers Type is accessible in Your second form(You made it public so it is) than You just need to pass this collection via proper constructor. Check my code below, I think it's simple enough. If You have any questions - ask in comment.

In second form create constructor:

```
public class UpdatePlayer : Form
{
    List<GroupsPlayers> _GroupPlayers;
    UpdatePlayer (List<GroupsPlayers> GroupPlayers)
    {
        _GroupPlayers = GroupPlayers; // here You are "Catching" the value You have passed in first form and assigning it to _GroupPlayers property
    }
}
```

In first form:

```
UpdatePlayer secondForm = new UpdatePlayer (smallGroups);
```

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to know about 'var' is that it isn't a variable type. It's type is statically determined at compilation time.

```
var smallGroups = new List<GroupsPlayers>();
```

is the same as

```
List<GroupsPlayers> smallGroups = new List<GroupsPlayers>();
```

This means your UpdatePlayer form has to take a List or subclass of it as an argument in it's constructor. It could, for example, use an IList instead. 'var' is just there to save typing for declerations, or to make refactoring cleaner.